# how to use the jquery plugins in app framework 2.0?

Tags: jquery, cordova

I am doing a PhoneGap project with the App Framework 2.0, but there is a error like

Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

when I use some jQuery plugins. Then I add the jQuery 1.8.3 into the project, unfortunately a series of errors is come.

The error list:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeTouchScroll' of undefined appframework.ui.js:2015
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'useOSThemes' of undefined 127.0.0.1:105
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'ready' of undefined
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to first use the appframework-jquery plugin to use jquery with appframework, use the jq.appframework.js along with jquery.js and appframework.ui.js:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jq.appframework.js"></script>
<script src="appframework.ui.js"></script>
```

[documentation: jquery with appframework](http://app-framework-software.intel.com/documentation.php#afui/afui_jquery)

`jq.appframework.js` can be found on [appframework github](https://github.com/01org/appframework)

Comment: I do this but then it throws `Uncaught TypeError: "Property 'promise' of object" #<Object> is not a function` error every time i try to call ajax